# Multiple files into a single ZIP using XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, zipoutputstream

I'm able to read from multiple files and create a ZIP, however, I'd like to create an XLS file(or two, for that matter) on-the-fly and ZIP them.
My original requirement is to give the user a set of dynamically generated XLS files in a single download. These files are available for download individually, but I'm unable to create a ZIP for all of them together.

I'm using XSSFWorkbook to create my XLS files and ZipOutputStream for create ZIP files.
If you must know, I'm using Struts2 framework.